# Как считать матрицу из файла в двумерный вектор?

Tags: вектор, c++

Люди, помогите, пожалуйста!

Есть двумерный вектор, описанный в классе. Привел только 2 метода из всех, лишние не стал писать. Сохранение матрицы в файл работает, а вот пытался сделать таким же образом загрузку матрицы из файла в программу - не работает! В файле матрица - неизвестного размера, но всегда прямоугольная.

```
typedef vector<vector<int>>::iterator matrix_iterator;
class Matrix {
 public:
    vector<vector<int>>v;
     Matrix();
    void SaveMatrix(int err);
    void LoadMatrix();

};
// если err=0 матрица не записывается,
// err используется, чтоб не было бесконечной рекурсии
void Matrix::SaveMatrix(int err)        
{
    if (!FileExists(FNAME_MATRIX) || err != 0) {
        ofstream ofst(FNAME_MATRIX);
        for (matrix_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
            copy(it->begin(), it->end(), ostream_iterator <int>(ofst, " "));
            ofst <<endl;
        }
        cout <<"Матрица сохранена\n";
    } else {
        char ch;
        cout <<
            "Вы уверены, что хотите перезаписать матрицу? + или -\n";
        cin>>ch;
        if (ch == '+')
            SaveMatrix(1);
        else
            cout <<"Матрица не сохранена\n";
    }
}

void Matrix::LoadMatrix()
{
    ifstream ifst(FNAME_MATRIX);
    while (!ifst.eof()) {
        int temp;
        ifst>>temp;
        matrix_iterator iterlvl2;
        vector<int>::iterator iterlvl1;
        for (iterlvl2 = v.begin(); iterlvl2 != v.end(); iterlvl2++) {
            iterlvl1 = (*iterlvl2).begin();
            (*iterlvl2).push_back(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tiva, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

1. Исправьте `vector<vector<int>>v;` на `vector<vector<int> >v;` это распространенная ошибка использования шаблонов (шаблонная магия не просто так имеет такое название)
2. Когда вы используете инкремент по итератору не надо пользоваться постфиксной формой т.к. создается лишняя временная копия, используйте префиксную.
3. Я могу чего то не понимать, но в функции загрузки из файла вы делаете не понятно что :-) самое простое решение - это читать по символьно и при обнаружении пробела (или что там у вас используется для отделения символов, вы про формат хранения ничего не сказали) делать `push_back` в вложенный вектор, а при обнаружении символа перевода строки переходить на  след элементу так сказать верхнего вектора.

ЗЫ: писать код за Вас никто не станет) да и дурной это тон)

Comment: Самое главное, что формат файла неизвестен.

Comment: Кстати, проблему >> в С++11 решили. Теперь можно так писать в шаблонах.

Comment: конечно спасибо за советы, особенно про инкремент, походу изза этого у меня появлялся лишний элемент всегда.
но, я уже на разных форумах наслушался "алгоритмов на русском"
я на 1-ом курсе, и нам дают сумасшедшие лабораторные, и я не могу сам написать этот код, как не объясняйте, т.к. совсем не понимаю эти итераторы.. помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Tiva, это конечно очень жаль, что Вас так учат (сразу с С++). 

Но на **любом** языке для того, чтобы прочесть прямоугольную матрицу из файла надо знать ее размер в файле (количество строк и столбцов).

В принципе, зная **формат** файла эту информацию можно получить, анализируя его содержимое (разные разделители и т.п.)

Вы пишете, что сохраняли ее в файл и у Вас все получилось. Вот и подумайте, как из этого вывода (мы-то этот файл не видим) вытащить сведения о количестве строк и столбцов. 

О порядке элементов: думаю что у Вас сначала идут все столбцы первой строки, потом второй и т.д.

Comment: Придумайте формат файла вы же сами и сохраняете матрицы в файлы.
Ну или записывайте размеры матрицы в начало файла.

Comment: завтра в обеденный перерыв постараюсь вам помочь, а то на ночь могу такого понаписать)) 
@mikillskegg спасибо, не знал) а как они отличают вложенный шаблон вы не в курсе?